# Getting Error in using parse SDK library in sample Android App

Tags: android

Here i am doing something with 3rd party sdk named `parse sdk` which provides some api for Android Platform.

I gone through this [link](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#android/existing) and try to do some sample work out for this parse sdk.

But After did all the stpes which mentioned on that link i am not able to run this test android application.

I am getting following error in logcat.

I already imported .jar file in libs folder which i made in root directory of project.

Code:

```
package com.parse.starter;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Parse.initialize(this, "ZVhSPsDKds8cerZ2jjDNXCpu332RHtix6Gp7YkDa", "poQXYifVzMd6haf56U5FQ13xeCxecdGippZeCMyVO");
         ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");

         testObject.put("foo", "bar");
         testObject.saveInBackground();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Error Log :

```
05-27 17:16:47.200: W/dalvikvm(468): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseObject
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity.onCreate(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:14)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-27 17:16:47.210: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit :

As per choop comment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/Parse-1.0.19.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Where did your new **JAR** file located in? `lib` or `libs`?

Comment: My guess is that you aren't adding the JAR file to your built path correctly.

Comment: I already added jar file if i didnt do that then i got problem at compile time. its run time error. my jar file location is E:\workspace\ParseStarterProject\libs i already added this

Comment: @Tim problem in this line  ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");

Comment: @user1089679 - Can you also add your `.classpath` file to your question..

Comment: @choop My question Edied

Answer (score 7):

Add the downloaded `.jar` file to your libs folder. Then in eclipse, right click on the `.jar` file and select `"add to build path"`. Then run your project again. This should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a few hours on the same issue and this helped the issue.

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)