# Android Google Maps fails after updating Google Play services from Rev. 6 to 7

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Ever since I updated my Google Play services from Rev. 6 to Rev. 7 from the Android SDK Manager (I'm using Eclipse 4.2.2), my app will crash whenever I navigate to any tab with my map. The app was working fine before the update.

Here is a line of error log that I found:

```
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:577)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.projectswiminsg.AmkActivity$TabListener.onTabSelected(AmkActivity.java:67)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:570)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1067)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:489)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    at com.projectswiminsg.AmkMapFragment.<clinit>(AmkMapFragment.java:23)
05-21 13:08:56.603: E/AndroidRuntime(11981):    ... 19 more
```

Any help would be appreciated =)

Comment: Post the entire stack trace, please.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited my post. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. If you also upgraded to the R22 tools, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990