# Class not Found Exception : Android

Tags: java, android

I recently added a external library .jar file into my project now getting this error. any suggestions?

`10-24 23:43:36.757: E/AndroidRuntime(459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android_alarm/com.android_alarm.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android_alarm.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.android_alarm-2.apk]`

Comment: clean the project, rebuild, reinstall the apk

Comment: Also make sure your Activity from the external jar file is listed in your manifest.

Comment: This usually means the Activity is not added in the Manifest. How many Activity do you have? And if you can also post your Manifest we can help you better.

Comment: Check this and follow the steps provided in it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744963/the-code-has-stopped-working-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-loader-dalvik and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22

Comment: what to set in menifest i have no idea :( how to set external .jar in menifest