# How to develop Android Navigation Drawer using ActionBarSherlock for API Level 8?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am to develop Android NavigationDrawer using ActionBarSherlock. My Manifest API Level is 8. I have used all the packages from Sherlock but still i am facing some annoying errors.

**JAVA Code-:**

```
package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

import java.util.Locale;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer


      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

      getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);






    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.

    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    SherlockFragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}}
```

**Manifest File-:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

**Error Facing-:**

03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-2.apk]
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066): 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-2.apk]
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
    03-05 22:56:52.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13066):    ... 11 more
```

This is the above error I am facing in my error. The error in the **Logcat** is also not clear. Please give some solution so that I can develop a NavigationDrawer for API Level 8 or for older Android versions.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Have you checked this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744963/the-code-has-stopped-working-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-loader-dalvik ?

Comment: @Philipp , Please let me know , how can i clean my project, because  never done this before.

Answer (score -1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-2.apk]
```

It might the problem of your manifest. 
Please add your MainActivity to the AndroidManifest.xml. Check for package name and other attributes if it's already added.

And then clean your project. Go to Project tab in Eclipse menu and click on clean.

Comment: I have already added the MainActivity in Manifest.... please let me know if any more things i need to add in the manifest...

Comment: You are missing first line in Manifest. Add this:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Sometimes giving full path of activity in manifest also works for it. Try changing your ".MainActivity" to "package_name.MainActivity". Also, this is caused by using third party libraries which use android support library. so check your libraries under java build path if you're using a third party library. Don't forget to clean project every time.

Comment: Yaa Man , i have added the .MainActitvity with package name but still i am getting the same error , i am getting confused now whether NavigationDrawer is possible in Android API Level 8 or not....

Comment: It is. I am currently on a project with this. Actually this error is occurred by so many causes. Most of them are silly mistakes. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo

Comment: No man , i have followed all your instruction , but still i am getting the same error ...

Comment: If you followed all the instructions on given link (there are too many) then i guess we are out of luck friend. You will have to keep looking and figure it out. However there are a few more similar questions. check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147241/android-app-classnotfoundexception-for-main-activity