# llvm-rs-cc: error: unknown argument: '-target-api' in Android renderscript

Tags: java, android, renderscript

The eclipse project folder shows a red cross beside it and doesn't compile.

On looking into 'problems', it said llvm-rs-cc.exe missing, so I downloaded it manually and placed it in platform tools.

Now I get this problem: llvm-rs-cc: error: unknown argument: '-target-api' in Android renderscript

What is the error?

Compiled against Android 4.2. Source libs: isoviewer-2.0-rc23.jar, xmpcore 5.1.1.jar, android.jar( 17) and jre 1.7

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [revision of ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) do you have installed? I can tell you that Renderscript was working fine for me until I upgraded Eclipse to the latest ADT 22 on my PC. With that update came the error message (when subsequently compiling an application with Renderscript in it)  "Error executing Renderscript. Please check that llvm-rs-cc is present at C:\Users\MyName\AppData....\platform-tools" which looks like the error that you first received.

The bug, evidently affecting Mac as well, has been reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55342) and I noticed, at the bottom of that thread, a workaround for Mac OS. I haven't yet found a solution for Windows.

Also, Renderscript is now not all that is broken, on the Windows side at least. I was getting "could not find class" debugging failures (having to do with the V4 support library) when connected to my phone, something I haven't experienced before. For this problem, [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596990/1620738) offers a fix which has worked for me.

Comment: For Windows, I simply copied the renderscript folder and llvm-rs-cc.exe from build tools to platform tools, but now I get the second error 

' llvm-rs-cc: error: unknown argument: '-target-api' '

No idea what's happening.

ADT 22 is a lot broken...it totally destroyed eclipse and I had to setup everything again..extremely frustrating.

Comment: Windows/Linux fixes have been getting posted to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55342 They're hit-and-miss with some users reporting success, others not. There is now one that works for me (msgs #32 and #33 on that bug report thread). This is a more generic fix so it will likely work for you too. Good luck.

Comment: @Avijit Oops. I should have addressed my last comment specifically to you. Sorry about that.

Comment: The #33 solution seems to snub the renderscript flag more than anything else, but hey, it's at least better now. :)

Answer (score 0):

This bug is reported as Issue 55342:    https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55342

After unsuccessful work around attempts, I found I had a backup 22/Feb/2013 of my entire Android SDK and my entire Eclipse installation. On reverting to these copies, the helloCompute sample Renderscript app compiles ok!

I suggest there should be a public source of working tool combinations, so there is an easy way to revert when "upgrades" are broken.
Don

Comment: I am fully functional with ADT 22 (for the work that I do, that is) following the updates that I applied as indicated in my May 31 post in this thread. I have many projects that I build regularly, some with Renderscript. No issues now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error - missing llvm-rs-cc.exe file. I got all the latest updates but still would not work.

Finally got a solution after several hours of frustration:
Copied contents of build-tools/android-4.2.2 directory which has the llvm file, to the platform-tools directory and then followed the instructions given by przemek(thanks!) just download and compile their c# code:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55342#c50

Answer (score 0):

download  `llvm-rs-cc.exe` copy and paste this file in your sdk folder and delete old `llvm-rs-cc`
dont install or run this file.