# Android + Facebook: NoClassDefException

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

ALL,

I'm trying to work on the code that was delivered before me and it's working fine on another machine.
I have an Eclipse Juno installed on top of Windows 7 and Facebook SDK. Everything in the project is compiles fine and FB sample are also compiles and runs fine.
However running my application every single reference to FB SDK gives the exception mentioned.

Do I need to set some properties on Eclipse or Android SDK to run the app? How do I debug such a thing?

Thank you.

Comment: your Facebook SDK is not correctly referenced by your project, have you tried re-referencing the library? also, if you're updating your ADT to version 22, try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22

Comment: @reidzeibel, thank you. Apparently FB SDK was not referenced properly.