# How to get eclipse (Android ) work after update ?

Tags: android, eclipse

Yesterday I updated my eclipse but after restarting it, it did not work , all my projects are giving me errors , I used help > check for updates , but it gave me there were no updates found !! 
and it keep giving me a message needs to update the ADT to 22.0 or higher version  ? 
I tried to install new software but it didn't work . 
Please help me with this issue . 
Thanks

Comment: What version of ADT do you have installed?

Comment: "all my projects are giving me errors" is a useless description of your symptoms. That being said, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Answer (score 1):

The new ADT 22.0 updates somethings in the SDK manager.

You will have to **update twice**. The first time to update the SDK manager, the second time to update the things that need the new SDK manager to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem this morning. If your Android SDK is up to date, go in Eclipse -> Help (in the top menu) -> install new software. In the "Work with" field, select

```
Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Uncheck the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" option, and click Next until finished. It worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In Eclipse goto:

Help->About ADT->Installation details

click on Android Development Toolkit -> and then update

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager and update the packages with "Tools" in the name (open it twice to be sure, it seems "Build Tools" doens't appear till you have r22)