# Could not find class

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

My project ran well until I clicked "**Help->Check for updates**" and installed some components in Android SDK Manager.

In general, there is no error announced in my project. But when I run my project, it causes an error

> could not find class com.androiquery.AQuery

I checked out again, I still can see the AQuery library in **libs** folder and also the reference to this library.

I also tried to clean the project and its dependencies, quite the eclipse, restart the computer, but it doesn't solve. 
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: try this if you have updated adt to rev 22. right click on your project. goto java build path. choose order export tab. make sure android private libraries is check. Clean and build. Also make sure you have android sdk build tools from the sdk manager. This only a suggestion

Comment: you are welcom @chipbk10. i could have posted this as an answer. but i have answered similar questions and thus would be duplicating my answer. so posted the same as comment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same issue as you and have fixed it this way.

Go to **Properties** > **Java Build Path** > **Order and Export** and check the **Android Private Libraries** box.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be one of the following reasons:

1. Setup problems: adding the jar files manually as well as setting the project type to use Google APIs. This cause problems for some reason.
2. You are calling activity may be inheriting some class that causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your are using ADT? if you are, you can download a .zip with all files in it. From the android developer site

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Raghunandan. The solution is right click on project. goto java build path. choose order export tab. make sure android private libraries is check. Clean and build. Also make sure you have android sdk build tools from the sdk manager