# Activity crashing when overriding SherlockActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

why does my application crash whenever I inherit from SherlockActivity? It's probably a silly mistake but I really can't figure it out! Just inheriting from Activity does work. Here's the code, layout file, manifest and the logcat logs:

```
package com.p4p.joinme;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm a textview." />

</LinearLayout>
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.p4p.joinme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

error logs:

```
06-07 12:03:22.613: E/ExternalAccountType(21992): Unsupported attribute readOnly

06-07 12:03:23.244: E/ExternalAccountType(21992): Unsupported attribute readOnly

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.p4p.joinme/com.p4p.joinme.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.p4p.joinme.MainActivity

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.p4p.joinme.MainActivity
06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)

06-07 12:03:25.316: E/AndroidRuntime(9285):     ... 11 more

06-07 12:03:25.326: E/EmbeddedLogger(239): App crashed! Process: com.p4p.joinme

06-07 12:03:25.326: E/EmbeddedLogger(239): App crashed! Package: com.p4p.joinme v1 (1.0)

06-07 12:03:25.326: E/EmbeddedLogger(239): Application Label: JoinMe!

06-07 12:07:33.959: E/ExternalAccountType(21992): Unsupported attribute readOnly

06-07 12:07:34.299: E/ExternalAccountType(21992): Unsupported attribute readOnly

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/EmbeddedLogger(239): App crashed! Process: com.p4p.joinme

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/EmbeddedLogger(239): App crashed! Package: com.p4p.joinme v1 (1.0)


06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.p4p.joinme/com.p4p.joinme.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.p4p.joinme.MainActivity

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.p4p.joinme.MainActivity

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)

06-07 12:07:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     ... 11 more

06-07 12:07:37.472: E/EmbeddedLogger(239): Application Label: JoinMe!

06-07 12:07:38.933: E/ActivityManager(239): fail to set top app changed!
```

Comment: What is the Target android version of your project? you have to set it to 4.0.3 or greater

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same issue about external library, maybe your external library is not exported to your apk, I suggest you to see this: [Could not find class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841050/could-not-find-class/16841371#16841371)

Comment: Thanks! There was a actionbarsherlock.jar unchecked and had to check it. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't linked the library correctly, make sure you added it to the library section in rightclick -> properies -> Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue on your code. Jst cross check with your library whether it is linked in your project.
Steps to cross check is  rightclick on projct -> properies -> Android/ java build path

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.p4p.joinme.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

clean your project and run..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has something to do with your error, but if you want to use Sherlock Action Bar you need to use their theme:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
```

Besides, if you just updated your ADT plugin you might need to check your Private Libraries in Java Build Path.

Right click on project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export(tab)->Activate checkbox next to Andrid Private Libraries