# start Fragment Activity from activity? "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity" onClick (View view)?

Tags: android

```
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3647)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4791)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    ... 11 more
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.qc.app.ffma.MapScreen
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    at com.qc.app.ffma.ui.PFZScr.gpsScreen(PFZScr.java:338)
06-04 13:38:23.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13869):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: you actual error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.qc.app.ffma.MapScreen`, not the IllegalStateException, which is only a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this class:

`com.qc.app.ffma.MapScreen`

Maybe something went wrong with your dependencies (libs/jars) - check this solution ([java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with external jars in Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857887/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-with-external-jars-in-android-project/16858073#16858073))