# ActionbarSherlock - the libraries I download don't quite look like the ones in tutorials

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am donwloading ActionbarSherlock from here:
http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html

and when I unzip it, I get a choice of folders:
- website
- actionbarsherlock-samples
- ....

But those are not the options I see in the tutorials where they import a library from this package into an existing project.  Could someone please explain which part of this download is meant to be added to an existing project?

Also, from the documentation, I saw that I need to set the minSdk="8" but also in other parts of the documentation I saw that I need to be compiled with API 14.  How can that be?  Could someone please clarify that point.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone please explain which part of this download is meant to be added to an existing project?

The `actionbarsherlock/` directory within the ZIP file is an Android library project that is ActionBarSherlock itself.

> I saw that I need to set the minSdk="8"

8 or higher, yes.

> I saw that I need to be compiled with API 14

14 or higher, yes.

> How can that be?

The two concepts are largely independent. `android:minSdkVersion` says how old of an Android device you are willing to support. The build target specifies what version of the Android SDK class library you are compiling against.

Comment: you know, after I added the actionsherlock library to another project, there appeared a red exclamation point next to that project. would you know how to fix that?

Comment: yeah, I recall that having faced this before. But I forgot how to resolve this. Is it a problem with actionbarsherlock library that I added? What should I do to it to fix it? :)

Comment: @Genadinik: Look at the build path of the project with the exclamation mark, and see what errors show up there.

Comment: @Genadinik: If you are on the R22 tools, try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31150/discussion-between-genadinik-and-commonsware)

Comment: I looked there and I am not sure if I have r22. But I do see syntax errors in the actionbarsherlock files.