# Cannot find class com.immersion android haptics

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to explore haptics using android via immersion sdk. (downloaded jar version= 3.6)

Reference:
http://www2.immersion.com/developers/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=119&Itemid=592

i have the following code (sample app provided by immersion)

```
protected TextView mTxtOut;
protected Launcher mLauncher;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("abc");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTxtOut = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOut);

    try {
        mLauncher = new Launcher(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("My App", "Exception!: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void btnPlayEffectClicked(View view) {       
    mTxtOut.setText("Playing built-in effect:\n. Effect: DOUBLE_STRONG_CLICK_100.");

    try {
        mLauncher.play(Launcher.DOUBLE_STRONG_CLICK_100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mTxtOut.append("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As soon as i launch the application, i get an error message "Unfortunately, MyFirstHapticApp has stopped".

I get the following exception "Could not find class com.immersion.uhl.Launcher referenced from method com.example.myfirsthapicapp.MyFirstHapticAppActivity.onCreate" at line mLauncher = new Launcher(this); in LogCat.

I've looked at http://www2.immersion.com/developers/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=2&id=170&Itemid=0 but was not helpful.

Comment: If you are on the R22 or higher version of the Android developer tools, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [The Haptic Guide](http://www.immersion.com/haptic/guide)?

Specifically [this](http://www.immersion.com/developers/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=495&Itemid=812).

Basically you need to make sure that both UHL.jar and libImmEmulatorJ.so are loaded. The second link provides instructions to do both.

Comment: Yes. I followed the same links to setup eclipse for haptic applications.

Comment: Ok, I was able to reproduce your problem. There are 2 solutions to this problem:  1. As @CommonsWare suggested, go to your Build Path-> Order and Export tab and select UHL.jar.  2. Put the UHL.jar in the libs folder of your project.  This should work. Also if you go to the Haptic Guide link I provided, there is a Haptic QuickStart link on the right of the page. Step 2 in that pdf talks about this issue.

Comment: SOrry, i was not able to try that. But thank you for your reply and for reproducing the problem. Sometime ago i had tried the solution recommended by commonsware and it worked out fine. Upvoted.