# swarm and libgdx demo

Tags: android, libgdx

I am following a tutorial of integrating swarm and libgdx. Link is here http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/libgdx.

I downloaded the source code provide http://swarmconnect.com/login?redirect=%2Fimages%2Fdocs%2Fexample_libgdx_swarm_done.zip. Nothing wrong happened when building. When I try to run the android app in emulator, "unfortunately, XXX has stopped" will pop up. And logcat is

```
06-04 20:58:37.107: I/dalvikvm(739): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-04 20:58:37.237: I/dalvikvm(739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-04 20:58:37.553: D/(739): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x15c610, tid 739
06-04 20:58:37.637: I/dalvikvm(739): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-04 20:58:37.657: I/dalvikvm(739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-04 20:58:40.808: I/dalvikvm(739): Could not find method com.swarmconnect.Swarm.setActive, referenced from method com.badlogicgames.superjumper.SuperJumperAndroid.onCreate
06-04 20:58:40.817: W/dalvikvm(739): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9558: Lcom/swarmconnect/Swarm;.setActive (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
06-04 20:58:40.817: D/dalvikvm(739): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000c
06-04 20:58:40.817: I/dalvikvm(739): Could not find method com.swarmconnect.Swarm.setInactive, referenced from method com.badlogicgames.superjumper.SuperJumperAndroid.onPause
06-04 20:58:40.817: W/dalvikvm(739): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9559: Lcom/swarmconnect/Swarm;.setInactive (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
06-04 20:58:40.817: D/dalvikvm(739): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
06-04 20:58:40.827: I/dalvikvm(739): Could not find method com.swarmconnect.Swarm.setActive, referenced from method com.badlogicgames.superjumper.SuperJumperAndroid.onResume
06-04 20:58:40.827: W/dalvikvm(739): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9558: Lcom/swarmconnect/Swarm;.setActive (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
06-04 20:58:40.827: D/dalvikvm(739): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
06-04 20:58:40.847: D/dalvikvm(739): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.badlogicgames.superjumper/lib/libgdx.so 0x412a0128
06-04 20:58:40.847: D/dalvikvm(739): Added shared lib /data/data/com.badlogicgames.superjumper/lib/libgdx.so 0x412a0128
06-04 20:58:40.847: D/dalvikvm(739): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.badlogicgames.superjumper/lib/libgdx.so 0x412a0128, skipping init
06-04 20:58:40.927: D/AndroidRuntime(739): Shutting down VM
06-04 20:58:40.927: W/dalvikvm(739): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.swarmconnect.Swarm
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.badlogicgames.superjumper.SuperJumperAndroid.onCreate(SuperJumperAndroid.java:33)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-04 20:58:40.947: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at dalvik.system.Nati
veStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 20:58:41.277: I/dalvikvm(739): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-04 20:58:41.308: I/dalvikvm(739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-04 20:58:41.557: I/dalvikvm(739): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-04 20:58:41.577: I/dalvikvm(739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

It said

```
06-04 20:58:40.808: I/dalvikvm(739): Could not find method com.swarmconnect.Swarm.setActive, referenced from method com.badlogicgames.superjumper.SuperJumperAndroid.onCreate
06-04 20:58:40.817: W/dalvikvm(739): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9558: Lcom/swarmconnect/Swarm;.setActive (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
06-04 20:58:40.817: D/dalvikvm(739): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000c
06-04 20:58:40.817: I/dalvikvm(739): Could not find method com.swarmconnect.Swarm.setInactive, referenced from method com.badlogicgames.superjumper.SuperJumperAndroid.onPause
06-04 20:58:40.817: W/dalvikvm(739): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9559: Lcom/swarmconnect/Swarm;.setInactive (Landroid/app/Activity;)V
```

But I added swarm project to superjumper-android project. Did someone meet similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Swarm.jar is not being included in the APK.

Be sure you've done these steps from the Tutorial:

- Link the superjumper-android project to the SwarmConnect library by going to superjumper-android's Properties > Android > Add... > Choose Swarmconnect/library > Click Apply > Click OK
- Link the superjumper project to the Swarm.jar by going to superjumper's Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries Tab > Add JARs... > Choose SwarmConnect/libs/Swarm.jar > Click OK

You may need to mark the "Swarm.jar" as "exported" by the superjumper-android project:  Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export Tab > make sure Swarm.jar is checked for export.  The Android SDK team keeps tweaking (i.e., breaking) the build process for Android projects that include other Projects and Libraries.  If you're using SDK v22 see: [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Finally, if none of that helped, check [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project) which has a number of different answers (for many of the different ways a jar file can not be found).