# Retrofit behaving differently & unable to parse when installed as a APK compared to installation through android studio

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have a simple network call that uses Jackson for converter with settings as below

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("*****")
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(new 

ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)))
            .build();

apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

and

getting a list of BGControl object using

```
public interface APIService {

@GET("endpoint/{ID}")
Call<List<BGControl>> getBGControlData(@Path("ID") int patientId, @Query("start") String startDate, @Query("end") String endDate);
}
```

and below is BGControl class,

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BGControl {

String Activity;
String Glucose_mg_dL;
String Glucose_mmol_L;
String Timestamp;
String Classification;
String ReadingType;

int intervals = 0;

public BGControl() {
}

public BGControl(String activity, String glucose_mg_dL, String glucose_mmol_L, String timestamp, String classification, String readingType) {
    Activity = activity;
    Glucose_mg_dL = glucose_mg_dL;
    Glucose_mmol_L = glucose_mmol_L;
    Timestamp = timestamp;
    Classification = classification;
    ReadingType = readingType;
}

public void setActivity(String activity) {
    Activity = activity;
}

public void setGlucose_mg_dL(String glucose_mg_dL) {
    Glucose_mg_dL = glucose_mg_dL;
}

public void setGlucose_mmol_L(String glucose_mmol_L) {
    Glucose_mmol_L = glucose_mmol_L;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    Timestamp = timestamp;
}

public void setClassification(String classification) {
    Classification = classification;
}

public void setReadingType(String readingType) {
    ReadingType = readingType;
}

public String getActivity() {
    return Activity;
}

public String getGlucose_mg_dL() {
    return Glucose_mg_dL;
}

public String getGlucose_mmol_L() {
    return Glucose_mmol_L;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return Timestamp;
}

public String getClassification() {
    return Classification;
}

public String getReadingType() {
    return ReadingType;
}

public int getIntervals() {
    return intervals;
}

public void setIntervals(int intervals) {
    this.intervals = intervals;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BGControl{" +
            "Activity='" + Activity + '\'' +
            ", Glucose_mg_dL='" + Glucose_mg_dL + '\'' +
            ", Glucose_mmol_L='" + Glucose_mmol_L + '\'' +
            ", Timestamp='" + Timestamp + '\'' +
            ", Classification='" + Classification + '\'' +
            ", ReadingType='" + ReadingType + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

below is the network call consumer code

```
final Call<List<BGControl>> graphDataCall = NetworkManager.getInstance().getAPIService().getBGControlData(13614, startDate, endDate);


   graphDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<BGControl>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<BGControl>> call, Response<List<BGControl>> response) {

            List<BGControl> bgControlList = response.body();
            if (bgControlList.size() > 0) {
             }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<BGControl>> call, Throwable t) 
       {
            graphDataCall.cancel();
        }
    });
```

However, the problem is when I run it through Android studio it installs the APK in device and I check it I get the response mapped properly and consequently updating the UI (I have already rendered multiple graphs! with this response!) (studio runs assembleProdDebug command).But when I am installing the **same apk** using command line in device "adb install -r ***.apk" the responses are coming null.

This is weird and I sent this apk to client :( before manually installing and verifying this apk and now it is a issue.

Please suggest a solution if you have faced similar kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might have used proguard to minify the code which changes the variable names.

You may try setting `minifyEnabled` false from the `build.gradle` file while generating the apk.

Check the answer of this question if you want to use proguard along with Retrofit:

[Using GSON with proguard enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31844352/5137352)