# Load json files failed with obfuscation

Tags: android, kotlin

I use this for loop to load a folder of json files

```
fun getJsons(): ArrayList<List<Item>> {

    var items = ArrayList<List<Item>>()

    try {

        var ims = MyApplication.appContext.assets.list("foldername")!!

        for (i in 0..ims.size - 1) {

            val res = MyApplication.appContext.assets.open("foldername/" + ims[i])

            val size = res.available()

            val buffer = ByteArray(size)

            res.read(buffer)

            val json = String(buffer, charset("UTF-8"))

            val item:AzAll =  Gson().fromJson(json,AzAll::class.java)

            val content = (0..item.header.count() -1).map { it:Int -> Item(item.header[it],item.items[it],item.count[it],item.notes[it]) }

            res.close()

            items.add(content)
        }

        return items

    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        return items
    }
}
```

The resources exists in assets folder inside `foldername` , now when i try to obfuscate the app with

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

it crashes with

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)

When i get back to

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

everything works , what's the problem ?

Comment: What is the contents of your `proguard-rules.pro`?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844352/using-gson-with-proguard-enabled

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly that your JSON model class (`AzAll`) is getting its fields renamed, and so the JSON is not being deserialized properly.

To fix it, you could either simply annotate the class with [`@Keep`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep), or add rules to the `proguard-rules.pro` file to not rename the class's members.

Comment: can you elaborate how to do this inside `proguard-rules.pro` given model name is `AzAll` ?

Comment: Also i have a txt file and it reads properly without issues on both cases and i have a model for it without `@keep`  why it doesn't work with json only ?

Comment: after opening apk with jadx i see class names appearing inside com -> package name any way to obfuscate them also @Ryan