# Java: IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a very weird bug.

In my Android app, I deserialize an object stored in the user preferences using :

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CodableObject>>() {}.getType(); // Line 1
ArrayList<CodableObject> codableObjects = gson.fromJson(json, type); // Line 2
```

Everything works very well when I compile my app in debug mode, but when I compile it in release mode, I get the following error on Line 2:

```
IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 73366 path $[0].e.n
```

Why do I have a crash in release mode and not in debug mode ??? How to solve/debug this problem ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: First check that release mode obfuscation does not mess up your gson class. Add `@SerializedName` annotations or `@Keep` / `-keep` rules as necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it is almost certain that it is the problem. So you have any recommendation about where to put these annotations ? I see many different strategies for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844352/using-gson-with-proguard-enabled Will see that on tomorrow, too late here to work on these crazy Android bugs! Will read your answer with attention. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd have `@SerializedName` on the fields to give gson explicit names to work with.