# Proguard: NoClassDefFound although it's in the APK

Tags: android, proguard

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-3
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at qu.a(Unknown Source)
    at pq.a(Unknown Source)
    at ta.a(Unknown Source)
    at td.a(Unknown Source)
    at tp.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory$PrivateManager
    at org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at avy.a(Unknown Source)
    at avy.a(Unknown Source)
    at avv.b(Unknown Source)
    at asp.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

To fix this I addded the following lines to proguard:

```
-keep class org.slf4j.**
{
     *;
}
```

However when analyizing the apk with APKAnalyser it seems that Log4jLoggerFactory$PrivateManager is actually included in the apk and excluded from ProGuard.

[image]

Larger image: http://picbox.im/image/172d169741-proguard.png

Comment: If you are on the R22 Android development tools, make sure your build path is set up correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Comment: The build path seems to be correct

Comment: I thought that it might be given your APK analysis, but I figured I'd mention it, as it's a common source of this error nowadays.