# Error after updating Android SDK 22.0.1

Tags: android, eclipse, roottools

With up-to-date Eclipse and SDK, my project is now not running on a 2.2.2 device.

It gives error creating class instance:

```
06-12 07:50:10.282: W/dalvikvm(16541): VFY: unable to resolve static field 6 (debugMode) in Lcom/stericson/RootTools/RootTools;
06-12 07:50:10.282: W/dalvikvm(16541): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 47 (Lcom/stericson/RootTools/exceptions/RootDeniedException;)
06-12 07:50:10.282: W/dalvikvm(16541): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x66
06-12 07:50:10.292: W/dalvikvm(16541): VFY:  rejected Lcom/system/cleanup/tool/MainActivity;.onResume ()V
06-12 07:50:10.292: W/dalvikvm(16541): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0066
06-12 07:50:10.292: W/dalvikvm(16541): VFY:  rejected Lcom/system/cleanup/tool/MainActivity;.onResume ()V
06-12 07:50:10.292: W/dalvikvm(16541): Verifier rejected class Lcom/system/cleanup/tool/MainActivity;
06-12 07:50:10.292: W/dalvikvm(16541): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/system/cleanup/tool/MainActivity;)
06-12 07:50:10.292: W/dalvikvm(16541): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020af0)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541): java.lang.VerifyError: com.system.cleanup.tool.MainActivity
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-12 07:50:10.292: E/AndroidRuntime(16541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could this be because I have RootTools in this project? I ran 'clean' but it still doesn't run/debug.

Comment: Can you reveal more from error stacktrace?

Comment: show the entire log please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK 22 somehow unchecked the libraries I was using, RootTools and Android.

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/)