# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError in AndroidRuntime Error?

Tags: android, pdf, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working on a github android project: ebookdroid. I import the code in eclipse, I select the NDK path for compile the c and cpp files. Once finished there are no errors. I run project on my device and in the log there is  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

```
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ebookdroid.ui.library.adapters.BooksAdapter
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at org.ebookdroid.ui.library.RecentActivityController.beforeCreate(RecentActivityController.java:104)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at org.ebookdroid.ui.library.RecentActivityController.beforeCreate(RecentActivityController.java:1)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at org.emdev.ui.AbstractActionActivity.onCreate(AbstractActionActivity.java:93)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
06-14 11:25:57.806: E/AndroidRuntime(16523):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:32:40.056: I/Process(16613): Sending signal. PID: 16613 SIG: 9
```

Why this error? In the class I import the right package of BooksAdapter... 
Someone can tell me what can I try?
Sorry for my bad english & Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you update adt to rev 22?

Comment: it looks like a build path problem

Comment: @ Raghunandan: I have ADT Build v22.0.1-685705
@ verybadalloc: sorry, I haven't found that question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using an library, and this is runtime exception. So just go to the

`Project Properties>Java Build Path>Order and Import tab` and check the libraries you are using.

It seems that ADT update 22, you have to do this manually: [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)