# NoClassDefFoundError BoxedUnit on scala for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, scala, noclassdeffounderror

After updating my eclipse installation to Android plugin SDK 22.0.1, Scala 3.0.1 rc01, my project was compiled but had the following run-time error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2195): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2195): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit
E/AndroidRuntime(2195):     at ******.MyClass$lzycompute(MyClass.scala:25)
```

I also had another error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2195): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala.collection.immutable.List
```

My project is separated between a library project and an implementation project.

How did it happen?

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22

Comment: I am mentionning the scala libraries, which is not in this other question - which is why I did not find it before, but thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the fact is that the project organization changed a little bit.
So now, there is this field "Android Private Libraries" that also needs to be exported. It is not by default. Ticking this box solved the problem for me.

Note that it needed to be done both the the Android Library project and the real project (GraphismeOne)

[image: Android Private Libraries]