# R.java issue, no solutions found in my research regarding the matter

Tags: android, xml, r.java-file

Hey so I have been having this issue for a few weeks and it's incredibly bothersome. I have looked at the other posts regarding the issue and tried everything without success. This inculdes:

1. Checking that all .xml files are named correctly,
2. adding  to the top of all .xml
   files,
3. renaming package (which it does not let me because it says I have to
   fix the errors first )..
4. I have also tried removing newer .xml files. no luck.

the error occurred when I did a routine clean the other week. I immediately proof read then removed the view_feed_event.xml file which I had just created and re-cleaned with no luck

thus far I have not been able to figure out the problem and it has persisted.

the only other thing I can think if is I added the App Engine SDK a few days prior to mess around with that

heres a screenshot, standard output for a J.java generated error.

any help would be greatly appreciated and I will make sure to accept the answer that resolves the issue.

Kind regards,
- Pete

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22. Try this. Also check if your resource files has errors in that case R.java will not be generated

Comment: Have you got "Android SDK Build-tools" installed? It's the third item down in the SDK Manager

Comment: Ken, I do not and I am downloading that as we speak... if that was the issue, you sir, are a gentleman and a scholar

Comment: Raghunandan, I have already explored that response. I googled around for a few days before asking. perhaps I should have asked earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the comment from Ken Wolf proved to be the correct one...

I did not have Android SDK Build-tools installed and there were several small errors in my xml that were not flagged as a result.

the resolution to this involved: Window -> Android SDK Manager -> check and install the tools then restart the ADT

thanks again ken for a timely response, you nailed it