# Build Android Support Library into JAR

Tags: android, build, jar

We all know Android Support Library has bugs. Some of them trivial and not fixed for years. I need to fix a few of them, but... how do I compile ASL source into usable JAR?

Comment: What I did until now - in Eclipse created a directory in which I've put all classes from support library source. I added android.jar to the project and it doesn't show any errors after this. Then I used "Export..." into jar, which finished with some warnings and a size very close to ariginal android-support-v13.jar. Unfortunately my Android application with this self-built library fails with lots of missing classes reported at runtime (meaning it compiles without a problem).

Comment: If you are using Eclipse with the R22 tools, be sure you have fixed the "Order & Export" portion of your build path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Comment: Hmm... I've got only JRE Sytem library and android.jar in that tab in my support library project. I've created this project as Java, not Android. Do you know proper steps to make it Android compatible?

Comment: I'd make it an Android project. The JRE library is not going to do you any favors. Just because you aren't creating an app doesn't preclude you from making it an Android project -- makers of reusable Android components do this all the time.

Comment: Nope. Same result. Builds well, but at runtime fails with unresolved classes, interestingly the classes are independent of the support library.