# missing android dependencies jars

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies

The first section of http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects explains that

```
With no other setup needed than adding Library Projects as a dependency in 
project.properties, a project’s classpath is automatically populated with:   
The content of the project’s libs/*.jar   
The output of the Library Projects.  
The Library Projects’ libs/*.jar
```

For some reason that is not working for me. I am using the [android-eclipse bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

The problem is when I look in the `Android Dependencies` folder, the jars are not imported from the libs folder of the library project. When I try adding it manual, everything compiles, but then at runtime it comes back to bite me, saying classDefinitionNotFound for the jar (here eg is `JSONArray from`json-simple-1.1.1.jar`.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Comment: Thank you. I checked it out. But the solution is not working for me. Should I just revert to the older version (21)? Or would that be ill-advised?

Comment: Make sure that you have made **no other manual changes to your build path** beyond what was listed in the answer I linked to. IOW, undo what you did for "try adding it manual". With regards to R21, I am unaware that there is a downgrade path.