# NoclassDefFound:javax.activation.DataHandler

Tags: java, android, email

Hi I am getting the `NoClassDefFoundError` when i add `activation.jar`, compiled and when I run getting error.

The `DataHandler` class exists in `activation.jar`

Note: I am using this one in android project.

The following are my error:

```
    06-25 15:19:22.237  10504-10611/?E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent(MimeMessage.java:1482)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:1066)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1521)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1505)
    at com.corpus.application.channellist.ReminderAlarmService.notifyReminderListener(ReminderAlarmService.java:90)
    at com.corpus.middleware.reminder.ReminderManager$2.run(ReminderManager.java:135)
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22. try this if you have updated adt to rev 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste your external jar in `libs` directory and then give `path` from your `libs directory` right click on `project`-->`properties`-->`java build path`-->`add external jar's`-->`select your libs` directory

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. i replaced all the jars with android supported jars. Now it is working.