# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception with library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library, java

In my application i'm using a library (called SlideMenu) included correctly in my project (I have not compilation errors) but, when I call this library, appear this error:

```
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.coboltforge.slidemenu.R$layout
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu.show(SlideMenu.java:334)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu.show(SlideMenu.java:260)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at com.tmp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:128)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17948)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-25 15:10:04.463: E/AndroidRuntime(11453):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how is Your folder called? "libs" or "lib" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22. try this if you have updated adt to rev 22.

Comment: uhm the name is "libs"

Comment: if it is jar file, right click on it and click "add to build path"

Comment: I already do this operation

Comment: make sure to select the Order and Export tab and select the check box as well for the new dependency..

Comment: Android Dependencies is select into Order and Export tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running adt rev 22, you might not be exporting your libraries. I don't know why Google did this exactly, but in the newest revolution you have to check to make sure you're exporting your libraries yourself.

Right click your project, click Properties, and check Order & Export under Java Build Path. It should look like this if you want to export everything:

[image]