# How to handle libraries used by a referenced library project?

Tags: java, android, libraries, buildpath

I installed a bunch of updates via Android SDK Manager this morning including Android SDK Tools 22.0.1.  This has seemed to be disastrous so far.  One disaster is handling libraries.  Here is the scenario:

I have a project projFoo that uses a library project libFoo. libFoo uses a dozen or so libraries or projects. In other words, libFoo has the following in its Java Build Path:
projA, projB, projC,...
lib1.jar, lib2.jar, lib3.jar ...

I used to need only adding libFoo to the build path of projFoo, and everything was working fine until I installed the updates.

After the updates, I have been adding projA, projB, lib1.jar one by one to projFoo's build path even though projFoo does not use them directly.  Without doing this, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError would occur when I run the app.

I have cleaned all projects and restarted Eclipse many times.  I also checked those referenced projects and libraries in Order and Export of libFoo, but adding those references still seems to be necessary. Is this the right way to handle this?

Comment: "Is this the right way to handle this?" -- no. You should just be able to check "Android Private Libraries" in the Order & Export tab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Yes, that is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the order and export tab of Java Build Path make sure Android private Libraries and Android Dependencies are checked.

Any libraries in .jar format should just go in the libs folder of your project. There's no need to add them to the build path.

Any libraries that are a project can just be added to the Java Build Path Projects tab, or if it is an android project, you can add it to the Library section under the Android pane.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Checking Android private Libraries of the app project is the key.  I have left the Android private Libraries of the library project unchecked, and everything seems to be fine.  I wish I had some in-depth understanding of this whole thing.