# Android SDK Tools update error

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I updated the Android SDK Tools in Eclipse but after the install I can't seem to use any imports as this is causing errors. I'm doing my dev work on a Mac.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? What kind of errors are you seeing?

Comment: android developer tools v21.1

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16603961/2345913)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Here is your answer.I also faced the same problem.. Try this.. it should solve it ! :) hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

After updating Android SDK tools, `Check for Updates` under `Help` section. If there are any, please update them as well and restart Eclipse.

Comment: thank you. I tried to do what you said but Eclipse didn't found any updates. Im going to download a new sdk bundle.