# Eclipse ADT 22.0.1 - Apps including library's don't appear to work any more

Tags: android, jar, eclipse-adt

I updated to a the latest version of ADT Bundle and now i can't run any of my apps that include my ad network jar file.

```
Failed resolving Lcom/nezero/testapp; interface 33 'Lcom/adsdk/sdk/AdListener;'
```

Then the app bombs with

```
D/AndroidRuntime(29555): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(29555): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dc4930)
E/AndroidRuntime(29555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(29555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.nezero.testapp/com.nezero.testapp.TestActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nezero.testapp.TestActivity" on path: /data/app/com.nezero.testapp-1.apk
```

And yes, before you ask, the activity is fully described in my Manifest file, this build worked before updating to the latest version of ADT.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.nezero.testapp.TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is very frustrating, I've got an app with a bug that needs fixing ASAP and I can't even get a working copy to debug!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22. check this.

Comment: can't believe that didn't come up in a Google search, or when I tried asking the question! Guess it's due to no one posting the logcat error or full ADT version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found an issue in the Java Build Path, Android Private Libraries wasn't checked!

[image: Checking Android Private Libraries]

After doing this all my apps started working again!

One annoying bug!