# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils error after exporting apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dalvik

Im building an application on the eclipse IDE and works fine after I build it and try it on emulator and on my phone. The problem is that when I sign and export the apk, I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

I looked for this error and read that the commons-io.jar file was missing on the /lib folder of the project, but after I looked into my project, I saw that the .jar was there. I also read that the problem is that at the moment of signing, when some .jar files are not compatible with the dalvik virtual machine, they are removed automatically. Is that so? If so, what do I have to do?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse and have the R22 or higher tools, make sure that your "Order & Export" portion of your build path is set up properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Comment: Yup, it worked! At first it showed me an error but at the second export it worked!