# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint

Tags: android, android-maps

I am using Google API for android. I wrote this line :

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(234120, 4885693);
```

I changed the properties of the project and included Google APIs. This is my manifest file:

```
<application 
        android:name=".Test"
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
```

The error is:

```
07-09 15:28:10.046: E/AndroidRuntime(7248): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
```

Comment: Seems a settings problem in your developer tools. If you use an IDE (e.g. Eclipse) add its name to the tags of your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should check out with this question:

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

I also had the same problem before.

Answer (score 6):

Add
`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

below `application` tag and above `activity` tag.

e.g.

```
<application 
    android:name=".Test">
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"...
```

Answer (score 0):

[This "using-library" node is used by Play to determine the compatible devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html), if I'm not mistaken ...

In eclipse, for the Maps classes to be recognized, you need to import Play Services as a project, then include this project in your own as a library. You will also need :

- com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES permission
- a meta-data node with the value for com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY

Try [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) for a kick-start tutorial ...