# Creating jar Library of Android project?

Tags: android, jar

I have a project that uses some `resources`.I want to create a library from it and publish it.I create a `jar` file with export option of eclipse,but it did not work.Then I search the we b and it seems that way works if and only if project does not use resources.But I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4085359/1043882).Here *CommonsWare* saya there is a way to create a jar file from a project that uses resources.But that answer has two link that do not open any page on the web and I could not test CommonsWare's answer.So my question is:

***Is there any way to create jar library file from project that uses resources?***

***Note***:

I read docs that say:

> If you have source code and resources that are common to multiple
>   Android projects, you can move them to a library project so that it is
>   easier to maintain across applications and versions.

But as I said before,I want to publish my `jar` and [docs say  we can not create jar file from library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html).And so I can not publish it.

Answer (score 3):

> Here CommonsWare saya there is a way to create a jar file from a project that uses resources.

Not in that answer. You can tell that by actually reading the answer.

> But that answer has two link that do not open any page on the web

Sorry, Google reorganized their site and broke the original links. The answer has been updated with current links.

> Is there any way to create jar library file from project that uses resources?

No.

You can create an Android library project that includes a JAR instead of Java source code. AFAIK, this recipe still works:

1. Create an Android library project, with your source code, resources, and such, and get it working
2. Compile the Java source (e.g., via Ant) and turn it into a JAR file
3. Create a copy of your original Android library project to serve as a distribution Android library project
4. Place the compiled JAR from step #2 and put it in `libs/` of the distribution library project from step #3.
5. Delete everything in `src/` of the distribution library project (but leave the now-empty `src/` directory there)
6. Distribute the distribution library project (e.g., ZIP it up)

And the new Gradle-based build system supports the AAR package for distributing libraries and such, though I have not played with this yet.

Comment: I tried your way some tilmes.But it does not work! For example if I have a class with name `M` in Android lib project (step 1),then I can not create an instance of `M` in Android project that has reference to distribution library project(step 6).

Comment: @hasanghaforian: If you are using Eclipse and the R22 (or higher) tools, make sure that the "Order & Export" portion of your build path, for both projects, is correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Comment: Thank you for your times.But I use `Android Development Toolkit Version: 15.0.0.v201110251216-213216`