# Refer to android resources from a library jar

Tags: java, android, android-library

I have an Android library project (A) which is used by several Android application projects. A library jar placed inside the `libs` folder of the library project refers to `com.lib.R` resource files (say images) inside this project.

When application project (B) uses this library, it may invoke some code that triggers the jar file in the libs folder to refer to resources that are referenced by `com.lib.R`. Unfortunately any attempt to access these resources results in the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lib.R$layout
```

If these resources are accessed from the `src/` folder of `Lib A` or the `src/` folder of `Project B`, they resolve correctly to an `int` value and can be used, but I'd prefer not to do that and keep the code inside the `libs` folder.

**My question** - Why does this happen and how do I get it resolved ? One work around is to get the resource ID programmatically using `resource.getIdentifier()`, but that can become a pain very fast. Is there a way I can still use `com.lib.R` from a library jar under `libs` without having to resolve it manually using helper methods ?

Here's an illustration to help you out.

**Resource access from library**

[image: Resource access from library]

Comment: "A library jar placed inside the libs folder of the library project refers to com.lib.R resource files (say images) inside this project" -- that should never have compiled, since, by definition, this JAR is not `com.lib` nor had access to `com.lib.R` when it was compiled. I have no idea how you got that JAR, and I have no idea why you would expect what you are doing to be reliable.

Comment: @CommonsWare Good catch. I got the jar by defining the resources first and then referring to them from another project. The java files were then compiled and placed into the `libs` folder of the library as a jar. The reason this was done was to avoid exposing the java files to end users. I'm open to your thoughts on why this is unreliable and how I can improve on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> and how I can improve on it

I am going to assume that your objective is to be able to distribute A and B in source form, but not the contents of `some_lib.jar` ("The reason this was done was to avoid exposing the java files to end users"). In that case:

Step #1: Create another library project (L) containing the source code from `some_lib.jar` and all the resources that it refers to (moving those resources out of A and into L)

Step #2: Create a distribution library project (LD) following [the recipe that I just wrote about earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574288/creating-jar-library-of-android-project/17574968#17574968)

Step #3: Have A depend upon LD, to pick up the resources along with the compiled JAR of L's code

Step #4: When you distribute the source, also distribute LD

My hope is that by creating a formal library project for `some_lib`'s code, and by having the resources it needs declared in that library project, you will be able to compile a JAR that will work for B.

Now, this is more complicated than I have tried, and so it's entirely possible this will result in the same outcome that you are experiencing. If that is the case, then you are out of luck, at least until you switch over to the Gradle-based build system, in which case L/LD becomes an AAR file, and hopefully will work.