# Android,How to use nested libraries?

Tags: android, jar, library-project

I have a library project in eclipse(for example `L`)and it has a class for example `M`.If a project has a reference to `L`, all things work fine and I can create inctances of `M`.Now I copy `jar` file that created automatically after clean/build in `bin` directory of `L` and place it in `libs` directory of *another library project* (for example `L1`).Now I have a project(for example H) that has reference to L1. But I can not create no instance of `M` in project H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through a round of experimentation with [the recipe for creating a binary-only library project that I outlined earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574288/creating-jar-library-of-android-project).

It appears that my recipe works... if the library project itself does not depend on other JARs or library projects. Otherwise, something seems to get messed up in the build process. I have not determined a workaround at this time.