# Thread Suspened on LatLng call(google maps api v2)

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2180    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2230 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 141    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1234  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

EDIT: Ok I fixed some things now I get this problem.What does this mean?

Comment: I fixed some things by following this tutorial http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html but now I get a different error so I edited my call stack if you guys want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

> that is the call stack

In the future, press Run in your IDE to continue past the point of the exception, so you can get a better stack trace in LogCat.

> Tried many many many different solutions like putting

That `<uses-library>` element is for Maps V1. You are using Maps V2.

> Also have the google maps library and jar added to the build path.

The Play Services SDK is an Android library project. You should import a copy of that project into your workspace, then add is as a library project to your app (Project > Properties > Android). If you did anything other than that, you will encounter problems.

Also, [make sure that the "Order & Export" portion of your build path is set up properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990), if you are on the R22 or higher version of the ADT plugin for Eclipse.

> my emulator's target is google maps api lvl 17

Maps V2 is not presently supported in the emulator, to the best of my knowledge. That would not explain your crash, but you will then have other problems once you get past your current issue.