# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable using actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, noclassdeffounderror

I need to use actionbarsherlock in my test project. Here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.actionbarsherlocktest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.actionbarsherlocktest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

but when I run as an android application, it is said:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable
at         com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:998)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:915)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:849)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
    at com.example.actionbarsherlocktest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem in how you have your project and its libraries configured. The compiler is unable to find the auto generated R class for ABS which probably means it's just not being generated. You should try reimporting ABS into your project. This video on how to get started with the library might help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the libraries properly?

Well try this ! this might help you:

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)