# How do I include the Android GridLayout support library in my Android project?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, grid-layout, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to add the backwards compatible Gridlayout library to my android project but I can't get it working. And, I have read all other articles on google and on stackoverflow but it still does not work.

Here is what I did, step by step:

1. Imported the Gridlayout project as an existing project into my workspace. I used the Gridlayout project that i found in my sdk, namely this path: `adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout`
2. In my actual project I then went to `Properties, Android` and added `android-support-v7-gridlayout` as a library to my project.
3. I then went to my xml layout file in my project and added a GridLayout to it.

Here is the code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

My problem: When I switch to the Graphical Layout of my xml layout, I see this error message:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout (Change to android.widget.GridLayout, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

What can I do about that? Any tips? This really drives me crazy...

Here is some additional info on my project:

- In my `Android Dependencies` folder I do have `android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar`
- In my `gen` folder I have a package called `android.support.v7.gridlayout`
- The project `android-support-v7-gridlayout` in my workspace does **not** have any errors

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of my project:

[image: Screenshot of my project]

Comment: Have you tried to restart eclipse and then do a clean?

Comment: sure. did that a lot of times with, rebooted and everything. no chance ...

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot with `gen`, `Android Private Libraries`, `Android Dependancies` expanded?

Comment: If you are using the R22 or higher ADT on Eclipse, make sure that the "Order & Export" portion of both projects' build paths are set up correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Comment: @J.Romero I added a screenshot. Any suggestions?

Comment: In my build (R22.0.5) the library is both added to my `Android Dependancies` and `Android Private Libraries`. Can you check what version you are on and possible update? @user2426316