# Android app can not find GsonBuilder class

Tags: java, android, jar

I have built a custom jar to execute JSON transactions. Inside of the custom jar I have gson-2.2.4.jar file. The jar is located in res folder.

When I include my custom jar in my app and try to run it I get the following RunTime Exception

```
09-13 14:25:39.411: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(988): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
        at com.company.mobile.rest.RestAccessObject.call(RestAccessObject.java:42)
        at com.company.mobile.rest.ContactsRAO.getContacts(ContactsRAO.java:25)
        at com.company.mobile.activity.ContactActivity$JSONOperation.executeRAO(ContactActivity.java:130)
        at com.company.mobile.activity.ContactActivity$JSONOperation.doInBackground(ContactActivity.java:89)
        at com.company.mobile.activity.ContactActivity$JSONOperation.doInBackground(ContactActivity.java:81)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        ... 4 more
```

Just as temporary step I have added gson-2.2.4.jar to lib folder of the android app. Still I got the same error.

Do I need to add something to my manifest in my custom jar to make gson-2.2.4.jar inside of it available to all other classes? Or, is it something with my android project structure?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: put it in the **libs** folder

Answer (score 0):

> I have built a custom jar to execute JSON transactions. Inside of the custom jar I have gson-2.2.4.jar file.

That will not work, unless you really mean "Inside of the custom JAR [you] have *the contents of* the `gson-2.2.4.jar` file".

> The jar is located in res folder.

That certainly will not work.

> Just as temporary step I have added gson-2.2.4.jar to lib folder of the android app

Put *your JAR* in `libs/`. And, consider getting rid of your copy of the Gson classes from that custom JAR and use the separate Gson JAR also in `libs/`.

If you are using Eclipse, make sure that [the "Order & Export" portion of your Build Path is set up properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990).

Comment: I have added gson-2.2.4.jar to lib folder still no go

Comment: And Yes I had gson-2.2.4.jar inside of my custom library

Comment: Sorry I meant /libs folder and not /lib folder