# WakefulBroadcastReceiver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android

My project shows error message that `WakefulBroadcastReceiver cannot be resolved to a type`.
I looked up for all possible reasons I can think of. I have set `android-support-library` and `google play services`'s path. Even my mapView works (if I comment below code) that means `google play service` is correctly added to project.

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Any idea why this gives error?

Comment: I have the same issue, for some reason this WakefulBroadcastReceiver is not found in the library even though I am using the latest version of the support library. I got a lot of stuff dependent on the support library that works fine, e.g. support library Fragments so I got a working support library for sure.

Comment: @user1948603 So how did you solve it?

Comment: I haven't solved it, I have right now exactly same issue like you but in my case (not sure if yours the same) I know I have my support library properly set up because I am using classes all over the place from that library, it's just this WakefulBroadcastReceiver that doesn't want to work for me.

Comment: @TobiasLindberg Even I use BroadcastReceiver in all activities and that works. Only this one is not working.

Comment: Well, in this scenerio it is not a normal BroadcastReceiver right? Do you have other code in your project using dependencies from the support library as well?

Comment: @TobiasLindberg Sorry I use LocalBroadcastReceiver and that uses support library. Moreover, I have integration facebook which uses it, too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure that you have the latest Android Support package added to your project. For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast) has a suitable `android-support-v4.jar` and demonstrates the use of `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: I use the support library same as my other team mates. It works on their machines.

Comment: @Akash: Either the JAR is wrong, where you have the JAR is wrong (should be in `libs/` for a traditional Eclipse or Ant project), or perhaps there is a mis-configuration in Eclipse (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990).

Comment: @CommonsWare Not sure about Akash but I have same issue like him and I am sure my support library works fine. The support library is added as you say and I am using a lot of stuff fully working from that support library allready like e.g. Fragments, CursorLoaders etc. but for some reason WakefulBroadcastReceiver does not want to be found.

Comment: How can I check that my jar is wrong? As Tobias says I use other classes from same library such as `LocalBroadcastReceiver` and that works fine.

Comment: @TobiasLindberg: That would suggest that you have an older JAR, from before `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` was introduced.

Comment: @Akash: Go into the SDK Manager, make sure that you have the latest JAR downloaded into your SDK installation, then make sure that the JAR in your project matches the JAR in the SDK installation. The R18 support package has a JAR with a file size of 556198 bytes and an `md5sum` of ed257a47cae11af1a55614055b879947. That is the same JAR that is in my GitHub repo for the sample project that I have linked to in my answer. You can also examine a JAR's contents via a ZIP utility and see if it contains `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have it already installed and using the same. Still issue persists.

Comment: @Akash: Sorry, I have no further suggestions, other than to make sure that you are importing the right class.

Comment: @Akash I somehow manage to get mine working. First using latest support library didn't work and then I went to Help -> Check for updates and updated all the android related stuff in eclipse followed by updating everything in the SDK Manager, restarted eclipse, opening it again, clean -> refresh, something like that and it started working.

Comment: Not the most clear obvious solution but that is more or less how I got it working.

Comment: @TobiasLindberg I already did that. My problem started in between the updates.

Comment: @TobiasLindberg Do you think that installing eclipse from scratch will solve it?

Comment: I used the support library in @CommonsWare 's example code. in the first time you copy it, doesn't work. I cleaned the project after that and it worked.

Comment: Android Studio : Add in build.gradle this line in `dependencies` : `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'` (before make sure you installed Android Support Library using Android SDK Manager)

Comment: Just to add to the @Laguiz comment: You can now replace 19.0.0 with 20.0.0 as there is a new revision of support library.

Comment: @VivekWarde: The link in the answer works just fine: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast

Comment: sorry, right now github server is down perhaps in india . Also github.com does not open.. I'll see it later

Comment: @VivekWarde: GitHub had been banned in India a week or so ago, but I thought that ban had been lifted.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for letting it me know. can you please send me your project on my mail vivekwarde9@gmail.com I will upvote your ans

Comment: sample project is not available any more

Answer (score 43):

I had this problem today here's how I fixed it:

It's due to the Android Support JAR not being updated like the SDK manager one.
You can delete it from your libs folder then do this:

1. right click project
2. Go to Android Tools
3. Add Support Library

Here 's a screenshot
[image]

Then go back to your class hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

It will import your missing library:

```
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
```

`Project > Clean` and Voilà !!

Comment: Searched everywhere for the solution and none of them worked. This is a lifesaver!!! Thanks!!

Comment: Don't forget to "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 7):

It's because of `android-support-v4.jar` file, make sure you have the latest. If you think you have it in your project just do a trick. Find same file in another project, say create new project with latest SDK. Copy it's jar file into your this project and replace the older one. Now import `import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;` and see it working..

Comment: My application uses external library project that by default depends on an outdated `android-support-v4.jar`. Updating (replacing) the outdated `android-support-v4.jar` on external library project did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest version of the support file. If you are using Eclipse, start the Android SDK manager (Window->Android SDK Manager). Under Extras->Android Support Library you will see if you have the latest revision (if not it will say update available). After updating the package should appear here: /extras/android/support/.

More info: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have updated 'Android support library' via Android SDK Manager but still cannot find WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

The solution is you have to delete 'Android support library' in Android SDK Manager and re-install it!

I have to say developing for Android is not delighting. Google deprecated c2dm and com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService so that all tutorials about android push notification become obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me
Add `v-13 jar file`
`Go to\projects\properties\java built path\add  external jar

And your jar file location is sdk\extras\android\support\v-13`

Answer (score 0):

The old v4 .jar file is deprecated!
Please uninstall and install again! Will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't worked for so the below procedure fixed my issue.

IF none of the answers are working set your target to `Properties->Android->Under Project build target Select the goolgle API's ->Apply -> OK`

This is obvious in case you missed to set Google API as your target.

Answer (score 0):

Add below depedancy in your `build.gradle` file
`androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0`