# How to call WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have read lot about `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`... but didn't get anywhere about how to even call this from main activity. whenever I search how to call `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` the result always shows me how to call `IntentService` from `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`...

Well to call `IntentService` we write the code "`startService()`" in activity or in `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`...
to call `BroadcastReceiver` we write

```
AlarmManager am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
      PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

But I don't find anywhere how to call `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`...
please help..

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051088/wakefulbroadcastreceiver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type

Comment: The reason you are not getting code to call WakefulBroadcastReceiver is that you don't call it yourself. Any BroadcastReceiver is called by the Android framework and not by you. Also, in case you have control on your MainActivity, why do you want to use a BroadcastReceiver. Just execute the lines you intend to put inside onReceive method of your WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver is a helper class that receives a device wakeful event.

you shouldoverride onReceive() method where you can call a service or perform your task.

WakefulBroadcastReceiver uses wake lock, so you must provide WAKE_LOCK permission in AndroidManifest.xml. WakefulBroadcastReceiver is implemented as

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        MainActivity.getTextView2().setText("Enough Rest. Do Work Now!");
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
        ringtone.play();
    }
}
```

in menifest add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

call AlarmReceiver like this:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

also add receiver tag in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
```

For full working sample see this link:http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial-to-schedule-and-cancel-alarmmanager-pendingintent-and-wakefulbroadcastreceiver-example

Comment: @wangz see my edited answer..also for full implementation of WakefulbroadcastReceiver follow the example ,..it has detailed explanation

Comment: @wangz Bro you have to had at least 15 reputation to upvote an answer...but you can accept it