# GcmBroadcastReceiver IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver, illegalargumentexception

I am working on FCM Push notification in Android, where I am getting this exception:

> GcmBroadcastReceiver IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

I have searched many question in this forum, but still didn't got help for solving it. My Log and Manifest patch is also given below.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.kolbeh" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
            android:value="id:85490######" />

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="dinewhere.fcm.CustomPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Error Log:

```
10-16 16:52:19.621 25906-25906/com.kolbeh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.kolbeh, PID: 25906
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.kolbeh cmp=com.kolbeh/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{2ac0a5c u0a888 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3259)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.kolbeh cmp=com.kolbeh/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{2ac0a5c u0a888 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
                                                                at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1505)
                                                                at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1461)
                                                                at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
                                                                at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
                                                                at com.parse.ServiceUtils.runIntentInService(ServiceUtils.java:37)
                                                                at com.parse.ServiceUtils.runWakefulIntentInService(ServiceUtils.java:68)
                                                                at com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:21)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3252)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: @U Khan: Have you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are running on Android 8.0+, with a `targetSdkVersion` of 26+. [You cannot reliably call `startService()` from the background](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services), such as from a GCM receiver. Instead, you should either:

- Switch to `startForegroundService()` and use a foreground service, or
- Switch to `JobIntentService`

In your particular case, the code that is calling `startService()` appears to be from Parse. You should see if there is an update to the Parse client that takes Android 8.0 into account.

Comment: Would changing the targetSdkVersion to 25 fix this?   I'm asking as I cannot change the call methods, but I can change the SDK target.

Comment: @clee2005: "Would changing the targetSdkVersion to 25 fix this?" -- AFAIK, yes.

Comment: I have this problem: the startService() is called from Parse. Does anyone know if a recent version of the Parse lib fixes this problem ?

Comment: @CommonsWare when I use startForegroundService() my notification are disappearing after service is done. However, I wanna keep it there, since I using it to receive notifications from Google. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Oximer: "since I using it to receive notifications from Google" -- a `Notification` has nothing to do with FCM, if that is what you mean by "receive notifications from Google".

Comment: @CommonsWare I have code in eclipse any solution for GCM ?. because I am not able to move on FCM and not upgrade code for the android studio.

Comment: @MrX: There has been no official Google support for Eclipse in a few years, and I have not used it personally recently either. Sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWareI found a solution at here, I need to update v4 / v13 lib
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051088/wakefulbroadcastreceiver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type