# Mashape Unirest Java : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, mashape, unirest

I'm building an application using Mashape's [Unirest library](http://unirest.io/)`(unirest-java-1.2.6.jar)` .
I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError` during runtime. I tried  [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596990/1842303)'s method. But it didn't work. Here is the screenshot of Java Build Path. Anything wrong in this screenshot??

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'm the author of [Unirest-Java](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java).

In order to use the library, you need to include the required dependencies into your project:

- Apache HttpComponents Client
- Apache HttpComponents AsyncClient
- Apache HttpComponents Mime
- JSON library

Using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is the preferred method: https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java#installing

Otherwise the libraries can be manually downloaded from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and http://www.json.org/java/index.html

But again, I would strongly recommend to use Maven. Also please update the Unirest library to the newest version because `1.2.6` is deprecated now.

Comment: I tried installing using maven plugin for eclipse . I created `pom.xml` file with your contents http://gist.github.com/thefosk/7325187. I did `Maven Install` by right clicking `pom.xml`and it generates a folder named `target` contains set of files with snapshot.jar file. You can see the screenshot here http://i41.tinypic.com/27y8q39.jpg And while creating a request it shows error. How to import Unirest?

Comment: After you import the library in your project, you also need to import the dependency in your source file. Can you add this code before "public class [..]": https://gist.github.com/thefosk/7343991

Comment: I meant to say that except Unirest other files are being imported using Maven. It created Snapshot.jar file in android project. Please see this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/auHM1SX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable to package everything in one uber jar by using Maven.

Please refer to this [post](http://blog.mashape.com/post/69117323931/installing-unirest-java-with-the-maven-assembly-plugin) on how to use Unirest in your Java projects.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't apply to many folks, but I was getting this error because I had an errant jar being bundled by gradle. It was a fat jar dependency that included unirest, was being stored in the codebase, and was not listed explicitly - instead, it was getting bundled with the gradle statement:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```