# HTTPClient Example - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient components from Apache for the following simple program and I see the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:726)
    at com.starwood.rms.controller.property.HttpExample.main(HttpExample.java:14)
```

```
public class HttpExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com/?q=java");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using

- Httpclient-4.3.3.jar
- Httpcore-4.3.2.jar

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works...without any error.. check the packages if you are using similar import .

```
package com.jai.http;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class HttpExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com/?q=java");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it seems to be working fine. I have other dependency projects and they are using a lower version of httpcore. I had to enable verbose mode to check where the jars are being loaded and was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: can you tell us what's the versions of Httpclient and Httpcore that makes this code works ?

Comment: Sorry mate don't remember. Should work in any version. Try with the latest version.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem with Hadoop. It used an old version of `httpclient-4.2.5.jar` and `httpcore-4.2.5.jar` in their shared lib.

I solved this by shading parts via the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

```
<relocations>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>shaded.org.apache.http</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
</relocations>
```

Comment: I have tried this with SBT but it doesn't seem to work. Did you ever do this with SBT?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for my use case. I was also using Hadoop. +1!

Comment: @Havnar In SBT you should use an ExclusionRule instead

Comment: SBT way of doing things 

`assembly / assemblyShadeRules  := Seq (
    ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.http.**" -> "shade.@0").inAll
  ),`

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the source code of DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory

```
package org.apache.http.impl.io;

import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable;
import org.apache.http.io.HttpMessageWriter;
import org.apache.http.io.HttpMessageWriterFactory;
import org.apache.http.io.SessionOutputBuffer;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter;
import org.apache.http.message.LineFormatter;

@Immutable

public class  [More ...] DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory implements HttpMessageWriterFactory<HttpRequest> {

    public static final DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory INSTANCE = new DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory();

    private final LineFormatter lineFormatter;

    public  [More ...] DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory(final LineFormatter lineFormatter) {
        super();
        this.lineFormatter = lineFormatter != null ? lineFormatter : BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE;
    }

    public  [More ...] DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory() {
        this(null);
    }

    public HttpMessageWriter<HttpRequest>  [More ...] create(final SessionOutputBuffer buffer) {
        return new DefaultHttpRequestWriter(buffer, lineFormatter);
    }

}
```

Are you sure you are using HttpCore 4.3.2? `DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory` try to resolve

```
BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE
```

field but can not find it.

Check your classpath for libraries which could contains another `BasicLineFormatter` class, maybe you have a HttpCore from an old version in conflict with the 4.3.2 version.

Answer (score 6):

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

one of the solution of **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE**  : This happens if we have two diff version of same class in our classpath…. […], So we first find that class(one version of class) , click that class, select "build path", then we click "remove from build path" . by 333ccc333

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. It looks like there is a problem while initializing HttpClient with HttpClientBuilder.create().build(). If you want more immediate solution just use new DefaultHttpClient() to initialize  HttpClient.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using Webpshere, make sure your class loading policy is set to "Parent Last", otherwise it will not work since WAS is using its own version of commons http which can be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, i realized it was when we upgraded to java 1.8, i just downgraded to 1.7 and works as expected.
Not sure why the version became an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also was frustrated by this and Eclipse until I realized that similar to Pat B's Webpshere tip, it does cause issues for Eclipse if you have the dependencies in the wrong order.

`Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export`

Play a bit around here with the order of core and client.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too, in my class path 
I have **httpclient-4.4.1.jar**, and **httpcore-4.4.1.jar**

However, for some reason,
the classloader loaded the class `org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter`
from **httpcore-4.0.jar** in a unexpected location and caused this error
you can use below code to check which jar it is using

```
try{
Class cls=Class.forName('org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter');
  println cls.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
}catch (Error ex){
  println ex
}
```

Hope this help~