# How to use Java classes in Talend

Tags: java, talend, routines

**I have the following three classes :
I tried making the routine of 1 & 2 and used tjava to call the main class and the method from 1 & 2 but I am unable to fetch those methods.**

1)

```
package page_scraper;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClientOptions;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.FrameWindow;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButtonInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlOption;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import page_scraper.UnitArray;

public class PageScraper {
    public void Scrape() throws IOException {
        try {
            UnitArray object = new UnitArray();
            ArrayList<String> unitList = object.getUnitArray();
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("http://www.bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_PanBMUData");
            List frames = page.getFrames();
            HtmlPage page1 = (HtmlPage)((FrameWindow)frames.get(0)).getEnclosedPage();
            HtmlTextInput settlementDay = (HtmlTextInput)page1.getHtmlElementById("param5");
            HtmlSelect period = (HtmlSelect)page1.getHtmlElementById("param6");
            HtmlOption periodOption = period.getOption(1);
            HtmlTextInput unitId = (HtmlTextInput)page1.getHtmlElementById("param1");
            HtmlButtonInput button = (HtmlButtonInput)page1.getHtmlElementById("go_button");
            String outputLocation = String.valueOf(System.getProperty("user.home")) + "/Documents/output.csv";
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputLocation);
            String errorLocation = String.valueOf(System.getProperty("user.home")) + "/Documents/error.csv";
            FileWriter errorWriter = new FileWriter(errorLocation);
            int i = 0;
            while (i < unitList.size()) {
                int x = 0;
                while (x < 365) {
                    String errorData;
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.add(5, - x);
                    String dateValue = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
                    System.out.println(dateValue);
                    settlementDay.setValueAttribute(dateValue);
                    period.setSelectedAttribute(periodOption, true);
                    unitId.setValueAttribute(unitList.get(i));
                    System.out.println(unitList.get(i));
                    try {
                        button.click();
                        HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage)((FrameWindow)frames.get(1)).getEnclosedPage();
                        String pageSource = page2.asXml();
                        int firstIndex = pageSource.indexOf("csv=") + 38;
                        int secondIndex = pageSource.indexOf("n\"") + 1;
                        String csvData = pageSource.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex);
                        fileWriter.append(csvData);
                    }
                    catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        errorData = String.valueOf(dateValue) + " " + unitList.get(i) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                        System.out.println(errorData);
                        errorWriter.append(errorData);
                        continue;
                    }
                    catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        errorData = String.valueOf(dateValue) + " " + unitList.get(i) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                        System.out.println(errorData);
                        errorWriter.append(errorData);
                        continue;
                    }
                    ++x;
                }
                ++i;
            }
            webClient.close();
            fileWriter.close();
            errorWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

2)

```
package page_scraper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class UnitArray {
    public ArrayList<String> getUnitArray() {
        String csvList = "abc,xyz";
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(csvList.split(",")));
        return list;
    }
}
```

3)

```
package page_scraper;

import page_scraper.PageScraper;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PageScraper test = new PageScraper();
        test.Scrape();
    }
}
```

**I made the routines for the above code(1) & 2)) in Talend and then used tjava to call the method but unable to do so..I also tried using tjava for all and did a onSubjob ok on each of the tjava.
How can I call these classes in talend and call the method ?**

Comment: **I tried loading the routines but then I am getting this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, routines classes in Talend need to be in routines package

```
package routines;

public class PageScraper {

    public void Scrape() {
        System.out.println("PageScraper.Scrape");

    }
}
```

Secondly, to use it in Job you need to drag'n'drop routine to opened job area.
[image: how to import routines in talend]

Then you can use your class in that way
[image]

Comment: I tried doing that but then I am getting this error : **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE**

Comment: Have you changed import page_scraper.UnitArray into import routines.UnitArray in PageScraper class ?

Comment: And try this: close your routine, in Routines right-click on your routine and click Edit Routine Libraries. Then add *.jar file with com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit , because it isn't default in Talend libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can easily [make a jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) file that contains the three classes then load the jar using [tLibraryLoad](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/5.6+tLibraryLoad) or include the jar in your [routine](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Creating+a+user+routine+and+call+it+in+a+Job) if you want to get more reusability.

Comment: I tried doing that but then I am getting this error : **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE**

Comment: @user1538020 Please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22330848/2037229) and its answers

Answer (score 0):

- As suggested in the other answers, you need to define classes under routines package.
- in case you are using Takend 7.3 & above, Right click on your routine and add it as Dependent package
- Get routines as a jar and in case using in bigData jobs, you may need to use tLibraryLoad to package it together with other dependencies..