# not able to find user defined routine in list

Tags: talend

I've created an user defined routine and named it as a FileCheck.

When I create a job and put tjava component am not able to find routine I had created using ctrl+space.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: in tJava mostly ctrl+space does not list everything. Can you try to do a ctrl+space in any other component say tFileInputDelimited in the filename section and see...also you should be able to user your routine in tJava though.

Comment: @garpitmzn, Working now cos I forgot to mention my class name in routine default comments !! :)

Comment: Hi, I've described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305483/how-to-use-java-classes-in-talend/) how to use routines in Talend