# Java client with Apache HttpClient to connect to Druid

Tags: java, apache, http, druid

I am working on ingesting and query data on Druid Server. But, when I query I just using the command line as below:

```
curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @quickstart/ingest_statistic_hourly_generate.json localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task
```

Can anyone tell me the way of utilizing Java client with Apache HttpClient to send that query to Druid server so as to get response. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this , but this should give you a fair idea of doing this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class HTTPTestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task";
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("quickstart/ingest_statistic_hourly_generate.json")));

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(content));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: I run your code above, but it have an error:  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:955)

in java line     HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

Comment: I used the latest libraries of Apache HTTP Client. For your error please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330848/httpclient-example-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-inst

Comment: Did You use Httpclient or both of Httpclient and Httpcore ? I just used Httpclient

Comment: Thanks, It work well.
I my project, The apache tika in pom.xml file may be confilg with others depedency. Thus, I created new project and it works well. regard