# How to solve an errror: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, error-handling

When I run the following code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com/?q=java");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:966)
>     at HttpExample.main(HttpExample.java:12)

Comment: What is the version o Apache HttpCore?

Comment: httpcore-4.4.10.jar

Comment: Did you try to use new DefaultHttpClient() to initialize HttpClient:

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

Comment: Yeah, that is working. But why is this not working?

Comment: Maybe you have two different version of same class in your classpath as it is described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330848/httpclient-example-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-inst

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Note that duplicate votes are _good_ things here - they signpost question authors to a ready-made solution. Please do not ask readers not to vote as duplicate - such requests should be ignored.