# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :-Could not initialize class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, httpclient

I'm working on a Spring webservice(SpringWSTemplate) and I am trying to  override `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender`
and I have a code like below:

```
public class CustomHttpComponentsMessageSender extends
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender {
@Override
public WebServiceConnection createConnection(URI uri) throws IOException {

CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpComponentsConnection conn = (HttpComponentsConnection) super
.createConnection(uri);
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder=HttpClientBuilder.create();
HttpClient httpclient = httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(uri);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
return conn;
}

}
```

When the code execution reaches line : `HttpClient httpclient = httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();`

I get the following exception

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.707 | Mar 12, 2015 2:48:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.709 | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory] with root cause
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.709 | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:726)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at com.utas.integrations.documentum.webservices.impl.CustomHttpComponentsMessageSender.createConnection(CustomHttpComponentsMessageSender.java:30)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.springframework.ws.client.support.WebServiceAccessor.createConnection(WebServiceAccessor.java:107)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:535)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:386)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:380)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:372)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/03/12 14:48:41.710 |     at
```

I use the jars in my build path and I have entries of jars in my classpath.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpclient-4.3.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/sapadtreco/lib/httpmime-4.3.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-ws-core-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/fluent-hc-4.3.jar"/>
```

Quick help is greately appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution? I have the same issue, also when I try exploding the jar , I see that the class file it is looking for is already present.

Answer (score 3):

It could be due to the invalid/corrupt/missing httpclient-4.3.3.jar file in the class path. Try exploding this file and check if its valid and contains the ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory class inside it.

Comment: actually it is not that ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory is missing - it cannot be initialized. had to look inside code to understand what was going on. to make the long story short, in my case, my application was referencing an uber-jar where a reference to an older version of httpcore library had crept, and although i referenced a later version in my main app, that older reference was picked up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864521/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-org-apache-http-message-basiclineformatter-instance