# HttpClientBuilder - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, maven, http

I have a Maven Java project that uses an HttpClient to execute HTTP requests. On my local Java Web Server everything works fine. But after I deploy it to the SAP Hana Cloud Platform I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:493)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:138)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:726)
at com.sap.hana.cloud.odata.service.OlingoSampleApp.getHttpclient(OlingoSampleApp.java:382)
at com.sap.hana.cloud.odata.service.OlingoSampleApp.getCsrfToken(OlingoSampleApp.java:374)
at com.sap.hana.cloud.odata.service.ODataCalls.doGet(ODataCalls.java:163)
...
```

My dependency looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

According to this question [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE from Mashape Unirest in Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864521/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-org-apache-http-message-basiclineformatter-instance) I tried to use the following code to get the ClassLoader Ressource.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.class");
return resource;
```

and it returns the following

```
"jar:file:/some/path/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.3.5.jar!/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.class"
```

You can see that the jar-versions are the same. Every similar question I looked at had incoherent jar-versions as the source of failure. Could there be another reason for this error?

**Update**

After the discussion in the comments I'll update my question:

Dependency tree:

[image]

So now I could see the version conflict and I removed the `neo-java-web-api`. The classLoader now returns version 4.3.2 again. But I still get the error from the beginning.

The new, complete dependency tree without the `neo-java-web-api` now looks like the following: 
[image]

Comment: Ah, but the class in conflict is BasicLineFormatter.  Instead of the URL you are grabbing, try grabbing the same one from the original question: `URL resource = classLoader.getResource("org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class");`

Comment: I've also tried this before. The response is `"jar:file:/some/path/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.3.2.jar!/org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class"`. This is the same version like my httpcore dependency.

Comment: Can you remove the `httpcore` dep and try again. This dep is already in the [pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.5/httpclient-4.3.5.pom) of `httpclient`.

Comment: Ok now the version is 4.1.4. `"jar:file:some/pathWEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.1.4.jar!/org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class"`

Comment: But now I Have an `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.Lookup`

Comment: can you edit your question and post a `mvn dependency:tree`, seems that you still have a conflicting `httpcore` version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still couldn't find a solution for the actual problem. But at least I could find a workaround. I changed the scope to `<scope>provided</scope>` and only use functions, which are also available in version 4.1.4. For example `new DefaultHttpClient(cm);` instead of `HttpClientBuilder.create().build();`