# HTTPClient "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>

Tags: java, json, ssl, post, httpclient

I'm using Httpclient-4.5.2.jar and httpcore-4.4.4.jar HttpClient components and I'm getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:966)
```

My source code as follows.

```
try {
        System.out.println("came to try catch");
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://bizz.mobilezz.lk/apicall/loanprepaidapi/v1");
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"mobile\":\"776037285\",\"path\":\"IVV\",\"loanAmount\":\"200000\"}");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer casmk34233mlacscmaacsac");

        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");        
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println("response is :"+response.getStatusLine());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Please assist me to get rid of this error. I'm trying to send request in post method and get json response.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793830/error-while-trying-to-use-an-api-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance

Comment: I tried from the link that you have given. It didn't work. Is there any way to check jar files compatibility? Many posts saying check the jar files compatibility. I got these jar files from httpcomponents-client-4.5.2-bin. But also it didn't work.

Comment: sorry, i dont know but try to find a working tutorial. i.e. http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-restful-java-client-using-apache-httpclient-example/ , as you see here in the pom.xml httpcore and httpclient compatible with the versions: 4.4-beta1

Comment: I had the same error when a 3rd party dependency pulled in an older version of apache's http core library. Check you dependency tree

Comment: how do you check the dependency tree ?

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer to my question and posting for your reference.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://bizz.mobilezz.lk/apicall/loanprepaidapi/v1");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"msisdn\":\"" + mobile
                + "\",\"channel\":\"SDD\"}");

        new StringEntity(json.toString());
        post.addHeader("Host", "mife.dialog.lk");
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        // System.out.println("status code is:" + status);
        post.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("status code is :" + status);
        resCode = Integer.toString(status);
        if (status != 401) {
            if (status != 409) {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                                .getContent()));
                String response1 = readAll(rd);
                System.out.println(response1);
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response1);
                resCode = obj.getString("resCode");
                resDesc = obj.getString("resDesc");
                System.out.println(resCode);
                System.out.println(resDesc);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("reason code is :" + resCode);
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked for me. Thanks.