# Unable to connect to hive server2 (SQL Exception, thrift transport exception and so on)

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, bigdata

We tried to connect to hive server2 database using the JARs:

1. hadoop-common-2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar
2. hive-jdbc-1.2.1.2.3.2.0-2950-standalone.jar

We integrated those 2 jars into Eclipse project and the code to connect to hive database is:

```
Connection con=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        StringBuffer jdbcConnectionString = new StringBuffer();
        jdbcConnectionString.append("jdbc:hive2://10.205.64.70:10000/default");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionString.toString(),"********","********");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but when we execute we are getting the error as below

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.205.64.70:10002/imsone: Invalid status 72
Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.205.64.70:10002/imsone: Invalid status 72
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:209)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dummy.connectToHive.connect(connectToHive.java:40)
    at dummy.connectToHive.main(connectToHive.java:16)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status 72
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:184)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:307)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:227)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:182)
    ... 5 more
```

Can someone please help me to sort out the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Error 72 is a bad url issue.  Is your hive2 Server running in HTTP mode?

Connection URL When HiveServer2 Running in HTTP Mode is:-

```
jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>;transportMode=http;httpPath=<http_endpoint>
```

where:-
 is the corresponding HTTP endpoint configured in hive-site.xml. Default value is cliservice.

Default port for HTTP transport mode is 10001.

Can you try below url:

```
jdbc:hive2://10.205.64.70:10001/default;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice
```

Comment: now we are getting the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:912)


hive-site.xml partial content is:


<value>thrift://10.205.64.70:9083</value>

 <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Also any error or code please update to your question not comment. It is hard to read in the comment.

Comment: There is a similar issue reported here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868242/httpclient-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance-at-org-apache-http-conn-s

Comment: I did not get any solution so I am trying to use qubol jars to solve it if I am able to achieve I will update here